# how can I write a resizing code for multiple png pictures that can exempt one of the pichtures?

Tags: python, exception, resize, image-resizing

I wrote a code that extract all images from the a file then I want to exclude one of the specific extracted pictures from resizing in the next function. How should I do that?

Here is my code:

```
def extract_imgfrmpdf():
    # open the file
    pdf_file = fitz.open(pdf_path)
    # # iterate over pdf pages
    for page_index in range(len(pdf_file)):
        # get the page itself
        page = pdf_file[page_index]
        image_list = page.get_images()
        # printing number of images found in this page
        if image_list:
            print(f"[+] Found a total of {len(image_list)} images in page {page_index}")
        else:
            print("[!] No images found on page", page_index)
        for image_index, img in enumerate(page.get_images(), start=1):
            # get the XREF of the image
            xref = img[0]
            # extract the image bytes
            base_image = pdf_file.extract_image(xref)
            image_bytes = base_image["image"]
            # get the image extension
            image_ext = base_image["ext"]
            # load it to PIL
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
            # save it to local disk
            out = image.save(open(image_path+ '/' + f"image{page_index + 1}_{image_index}.{image_ext}", "wb"))
    return (out)

def resize():
    #assign the path of the images to a variable:
    f = image_path

    #By using os.listdir() function you can read all the file names in a directory.
    for file in os.listdir(f):
        f_img = f+"/"+file
        #open the image
        img = Image.open(f_img)
        #resize the image
        img = img.resize((253, 250))
        #saved the image
        out2 = img.save(f_img)
    return(out2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have gotten the resizing to work, and you are only trying to skip a specific page or something along this line.

```
f = image_path
dir_list = os.listdir(f) 
unwated_file_name = "pagexx" # the name of page you don't want to be resized

for i in range(len(dir_list)):
  if dir_list[i] == unwated_file_name:
    del_index = i
  else:
    pass

dir_list.pop(del_index)
print(dir_list) #can now see what pages that will be resized
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. In fact, my files have only one page which contains 8 pictures which one of them is the main pictures and the other 7 pictures are part of it. When the extracting process is done, I want to keep the main picture size but resize the other 7 images.

Comment: Ok I think I understand a little better now. However, I think you can still use the code if you know which image you don’t want to resize. Let say it's image_5.ext. Then you would use the code and swap pagexx with image_5.ext or something like that. And then use dir_list instead of os.listdir(f). Hope it helps